# Getting Detox can't seem to connect to the test app(s)! on Android

Tags: android, react-native, end-to-end, detox

Getting Detox can't seem to connect to the test app(s)! on Android

I'm encountering an issue with Detox, a testing framework for mobile apps, where it's unable to establish a connection with the test app(s) I'm trying to test. The execution hangs and I'm not sure how to resolve it.

I've followed the troubleshooting guide provided by the Detox team (link: https://wix.github.io/Detox/docs/troubleshooting/running-tests#tests-execution-hangs), but I'm still unable to identify the root cause of the problem.

Here are some details of my setup:

I'm using Detox for testing a mobile app on both Android and iOS platforms.
I've verified that the necessary configurations, such as device ID, are correct and up to date.
I've confirmed that the devices are properly connected to my computer via USB, and USB debugging is enabled.
I've checked for any relevant error messages or warnings, but nothing stands out.

Here are the dependency versions we used:

Node version : 14.21.2
React native version: 0.65.0
Detox Version: 20.8.0
Jest: 29.2.1
Java: 11.0.17

I'm not sure what else I can do to troubleshoot this issue. Are there any specific steps or considerations I might be missing? Has anyone else encountered a similar problem with Detox and found a solution?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: have you done the Project setup for Android correctly ? Please check this link : https://wix.github.io/Detox/docs/introduction/project-setup/#step-4-additional-android-configuration

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue then I follow steps for android, and its working fine.

All steps are mentioned in detox following link

```
https://wix.github.io/Detox/docs/introduction/project-setup/
```

Answer (score -2):

It sounds like you have already gone through the basic troubleshooting steps for Detox, but are still experiencing issues connecting to the test app on Android. Here are some additional steps you can take to try and resolve the issue:

Check the logs: Detox provides detailed logs that can help identify the cause of the issue. Run your tests with the --loglevel verbose flag to see more detailed logs. Check the logs for any errors or warnings related to device connectivity.

Verify device connection: Double-check that your device is properly connected to your computer via USB, and that USB debugging is enabled. If you have multiple devices connected, make sure the correct device ID is specified in the Detox configuration.

Verify app installation: Make sure the app you are testing is properly installed on the device. Try uninstalling and reinstalling the app to see if that resolves the issue.

Check ADB version: Make sure you have the latest version of Android Debug Bridge (ADB) installed on your system. You can check your ADB version by running adb version in your terminal.

Try restarting ADB server: Sometimes restarting the ADB server can help resolve connectivity issues. You can restart the ADB server by running adb kill-server and then adb start-server in your terminal.

Check for firewall issues: If you are running a firewall on your system, it could be blocking the connection to the device. Try temporarily disabling the firewall to see if that resolves the issue.

Check for antivirus issues: Some antivirus software can interfere with the device connection. Try temporarily disabling your antivirus software to see if that resolves the issue.

If none of these steps help, it's possible that there may be a compatibility issue between Detox and your specific device or Android version. In that case, you may want to check the Detox GitHub issues page to see if anyone else has reported a similar issue, or try reaching out to the Detox community for help.

Reference: https://chat.openai.com/